# Remove pip3 from .local/bin/pip3

Tags: apt, pip

I try to clean my python installation(s) on ubuntu 18-04. I did different things with **apt-get remove**, but there is still a pip3 on my **~/.local/bin/pip3** that I can't remove.

How can I remove it (safely)?

Comment: I suspect the `~/.local/bin/pip3` file was added by you (either by command, or via a script or command you have run).  The `apt` & `dpkg` tools add the binary in `/usr/bin/pip3`  (not in the user directory)

Comment: @guiverc `pip` itself add this directory as you are normally not supposed to run pip by `sudo` and this directory is where your installed libraries end up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing python from your system is something you not want to do, as many of Ubuntu's commands and tools depend on it. So you most likely will render your system unusable. But to come back to your actual question about removing the user pip3 directory, the answer simply is:

```
rm -r ~/.local/bin/pip3
```

As stated from me before you do this whole python removal on your system on your own risk, so not say you haven't be warned.

Comment: Thanks, I did this command and reinstall pip3. All seems clean (for) now.